# In which context are blocks executed that are passed to a method in ruby?

Tags: ruby, yield

I learned that you can pass a whole block of code to a method in ruby. This block can be executed from within the method. My question is: Which context will it have? Will it be treated just like other statements in the receiving method, or are they treated like statements in the caller method? Or maybe there is a special third way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Local variables follow lexical scope.
- Block variables have scope within the block.
- Global variables have access globally.
- Everything else depends on the method that takes the block. For example, `instance_eval` evaluates the block within the context of the receiver. `class_eval` evaluates the block within the context of the class of the receiver.

Comment: thanks for the answer, helping a lot.
could you elaborate on the first bullet point please? on googling lexical scope in ruby, many sites tell me, that ruby does not have that.

Comment: An example will be `foo = 2; [:a].each{p foo}`.